# How to only read a file between certain phrases

Tags: python

Just a basic question. I know how to read information from a file etc but how would I go about only including the lines that are in between certain lines?

Say I have this :

Information Included in file but before "beginning of text"

" Beginning of text "

information I want

" end of text "

Information included in file but after the "end of text"

Thank you for any help you can give to get me started.

Comment: did any of the answers solve your problem, have you come any further?

Answer (score 1):

You can read the file in line by line until you reach the start-markerline, then do something with the lines (print them, store them in a `list`, etc) until you reach the end-markerline.

```
with open('myfile.txt') as f:
    line = f.readline()
    while line != ' Beginning of text \n':
        line = f.readline()
    while line != ' end of text \n':
        # add code to do something with the line here
        line = f.readline()
```

Make sure to exactly match the start- and end-markerlines. In your example they have a leading and trailing blank.

Answer (score 1):

Yet another way to do it, is to use two-argument version of `iter()`:

```
start = '" Beginning of text "\n'
end = '" end of text "\n'
with open('myfile.txt') as f:
    for line in iter(f.readline, start):
        pass
    for line in iter(f.readline, end):
        print line
```

see https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#iter for details

Answer (score 0):

I would just read the file line by line and check each line if it matches beginning or end string. The boolean readData then indicates if you are between beginning and end and you can read the actual information to another variable.

```
# Open the file
f = open('myTextFile.txt')
# Read the first line 
line = f.readline()
readData=false;

# If the file is not empty keep reading line one at a time
# until the file is empty
while line:
    # Check if line matches beginning
    if line == "Beginning of text":
        readData=true;

    # Check if line matches end
    if line == "end of text"
        readData=false;

    # We are between beginning and end
    if readData:
        (...)
    line = f.readline()
f.close()
```

Comment: Why do you continue to read in lines after the end-marker has been found?

Comment: That is a good point. That could be stopped once the end is reached.